# SubMenus on tablets get shown at wrong position when targeting API level 26

Tags: android, position, tablet, submenu, android-8.0-oreo

After updating the *compileSdkVersion* and *targetSdkVersion* level to **26**, on tablet devices with API level 20 to 25, submenus get shown at the center of the Toolbar (or ActionBar), not next to the menu.

**Screenshots for a better understanding:**

[Expected result, submenu next to the menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omSID.png)

[Actual result, there's a gap between the submenu and the menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqlNP.png)

I assume it's a bug within the Support library 26? When targeting Api level 24 this issue doesn't occur on any device.

Has anyone also experienced this issue and maybe a fix?

Code from a test project:

The menu XML:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:emma="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_send_mail"
    android:icon="@null"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:title="send"
    emma:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_save_draft"
    android:icon="@null"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    android:title="save"
    emma:showAsAction="never"/>
```

The *onCreateOptionsMenu* method

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.message_compose, menu);

    SubMenu debugSub = menu.addSubMenu("More actions");
    debugSub.add("Action 1");
    debugSub.add("Action 2");

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: We've faced the same problem. Support Library 27.0.2 still has this issue. I think you should open a discussion here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:192633%2B

Comment: Created an issue - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69906575

Comment: Thank you very much. I wanted to create one after work. :)

Comment: @ramon Did you get the solution?

Comment: @RohanLodhi Hi, it appeared to be an issue in Support Library 26 (and partly 27). I haven't seen this issue again since using SDK Version 28 and its Support Library. :)